# Spring Hibernate Transaction: Data is not getting saved

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions, spring-transactions

I have created a simple spring application, where were have an accounts table with account number(Primary key), account type, balance

When ever I try to update data that is not happening, it still shows the old value.

Here is my configuration file.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans 
  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config/>

    <bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jlcindiadb"/>
        <property name="username" value="root"/>
        <property name="password" value="123"/> 
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">

        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>      
        <property name="mappingResources">
            <list>
                <value>com/jlcindia/spring/Account.hbm.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" >update</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>         

        <bean id="hibernateTemp" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate" 
                    autowire="constructor"/>      

        <bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager" autowire="constructor"/>

        <bean id="accdao" class="com.jlcindia.spring.HibernateAccountDAO"/>                      
        <bean id="as" class="com.jlcindia.spring.AccountServiceImpl"/>

    </beans>
```

Snippet for deposite function.

```
public void deposit(int accno, double amt) {
    TransactionDefinition txDef= new DefaultTransactionDefinition();
    TransactionStatus ts= txManager.getTransaction(txDef);
    Account acc=htemp.load(Account.class,accno,LockMode.READ);
    double cbal=acc.getBal();       
    acc.setBal(cbal+amt);
    htemp.update(acc);
    txManager.commit(ts);       
}
```

Initially my table contains the following records:

```
         Account     Account    Balance
           No         Type

Account1: 101         SA        1000

Account2: 102         SA        2000

Account3: 103         CA        3000
```

Now on updating the data. That is after depositing the data it still shows the same balance.
Why Such a behavior? Please explain..

Update :

Class containing Deposit function.

```
import org.hibernate.LockMode;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.TransactionDefinition;
import org.springframework.transaction.TransactionStatus;
import org.springframework.transaction.support.DefaultTransactionDefinition;

public class HibernateAccountDAO implements AccountDAO{

@Autowired
HibernateTemplate htemp=null;

@Autowired
HibernateTransactionManager txManager=null;

@Override
public void deposit(int accno, double amt) {
    TransactionDefinition txDef= new DefaultTransactionDefinition();
    TransactionStatus ts= txManager.getTransaction(txDef);
    Account acc=htemp.load(Account.class,accno,LockMode.READ);
    double cbal=acc.getBal();
    //int cbal=(int)bal;

    acc.setBal(cbal+amt);
    htemp.update(acc);      
    txManager.commit(ts);
    //System.out.println("Acc get Account number "+acc.getAccno());
    //System.out.println("Acc get Account type "+acc.getAtype());
    //System.out.println("Acc get Balance "+acc.getBal());
}


@Override
public void withdraw(int accno, double amt) {
    TransactionDefinition txDef= new DefaultTransactionDefinition();
    TransactionStatus ts= txManager.getTransaction(txDef);
    Account acc=htemp.load(Account.class,accno,LockMode.READ);
    double cbal=acc.getBal();
    if(cbal>500+amt){
        acc.setBal(cbal-amt);
        htemp.update(acc);          
    }else{
        throw new InSufficientFundsException();         
    }
    txManager.commit(ts);

}

@Override
public void fundsTransfer(int saccno, int daccno, double amt) {
    TransactionDefinition txDef= new DefaultTransactionDefinition();
    TransactionStatus ts= txManager.getTransaction(txDef);
    try{
    Account acc1=htemp.load(Account.class,daccno,LockMode.READ);
    double dcbal=acc1.getBal();
    acc1.setBal(dcbal+amt);
    htemp.update(acc1);

    Account acc2=htemp.load(Account.class,saccno,LockMode.READ);
    double scbal=acc2.getBal();
    if(scbal>=500+amt){
        acc2.setBal(scbal-amt);         
        htemp.update(acc2);
    }else{
        throw new InSufficientFundsException();
    }
    txManager.commit(ts);

    }catch(Exception e){
        txManager.rollback(ts);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public double getBalance(int accno) {
    TransactionDefinition txDef= new DefaultTransactionDefinition();
    TransactionStatus ts= txManager.getTransaction(txDef);
    Account acc=htemp.load(Account.class,accno,LockMode.READ);
    double cbal=acc.getBal();
    return cbal;        
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have not provided session factory to hibernate template and transaction manager. Try to test again by modify the particular xml part, as shown below? :

```xml
<bean id="hibernateTemp" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate" 
        autowire="constructor"/>
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property> 
</bean>                 

<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager" 
        autowire="constructor">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property> 
</bean>
```

My simulation snippet:

```
Resource r=new ClassPathResource("applicationContext.xml");  
BeanFactory factory=new XmlBeanFactory(r);  
HibernateTemplate template = (HibernateTemplate) factory.getBean("template");
HibernateTransactionManager txManager = (HibernateTransactionManager) factory.getBean ("txManager");
TransactionDefinition txDef= new DefaultTransactionDefinition();
TransactionStatus ts= txManager.getTransaction(txDef);
Employee acc=template.load(Employee.class,114,LockMode.READ);      
acc.setName("varun");
template.update(acc);
txManager.commit(ts);
```

Comment: Thanks for showing interest, I implemented the above suggestion. but still it gives the same result. That is data is still not getting saved.

Comment: If your session factory bean is called `sessionFactory` Hibernate picks it up automatically. It's only if your bean is called something different that you have to specify it.

Comment: @JamesMassey, ok my problem still exist, any idea how to over come that.

Comment: Nope, I only use Hibernate 4.

Comment: @JamesMassey, thanks edit suggested and infor of session factory.

Comment: @user2900314, I simulate your function and it is working actually. Just that I use BeanFactory to get HibernateTemplate and HibernateTransactionManager object since i don't know how does it declare in your code snippet. Can you post the class of deposite function? Above is the snippet of my simulation.

Comment: @HaRLoFei, I have updated my question. please have a look at it. The code as such is working fine. But the values are not getting updated. Is there anything more that I need to do before/after commit?

Comment: @user2900314, HibernateTemplate and HibernateTransactionManager in HibernateAccountDAO class seems fine, can you post Account.hbm.xml,Account class and the class that call Deposit function as well? I may worry that balance property is missing in hbm xml and cause this issue.